# Perform onClick on a view inside a fragment based on bundle param

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

Problem:
I need to perform onClick on a view present in Fragment depending upon the location from which the activity was launched.

I have setArguments on Bundle in **myActivity's** **onCreate**:

```
final String launchedFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra(LAUNCHED_FROM);
if (launchedFrom!=null) {
    bundle.putBoolean("myStr", true);
}
```

Now, I fetch the argument from **onCreateView** of **Fragment** and perform click on 3rd item in the list:

```
if (this.getArguments().getBoolean("myStr")) {
    mOptions.getAdapter().getView(3, null, null).callOnClick();
}
```

This opens the 3rd item on the list. Now, when I press back button the onCreateView is getting called again and the control is redirected to the 3rd item in the list as the bundle arguments have not changed on backPress.

I want to navigate back to the place from where the activity was called when I press the back button.

This is the code that is called when using .callonClick()

```
@Override
public void onViewSelected(List<Entry> faqs) {
    Fragment fragment = FragmentB.newInstance(new ArrayList<>(faqs));
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.activity_frame_layout, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(FragmentB.TAG)
            .commit();
}
```

Solution#1: Not the best approach, if I move the code of **onCreateView** to **onCreate**, but I think there needs to be a better approach to solve this.

Comment: Simulating a click seems like you are making things much more complicated than necessary. If you have two different ways to perform the same logic, that logic should be in a central method which you can call from any event handlers that need it.

Comment: Simulating onClick is just a temporary solution to make things work. The real problem is to handle the backpress

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Include more complete code along with your verbal description. When you simulate the click on a view in the fragment does it automatically replace that fragment with another one? Can you just load the second fragment directly instead?